# How to open partial view with $window.open()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

How can i set url in `$window.open()` .. something like this `$window.open("/account/something")` ? I tried this but i get always default page without anything.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Do you have more code to explain your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
$window.open('/controller-Name/action-method-Name');};
```

Which will find the action method and return the view.

If problem still persist, debug your action method once.